# Compare 3 arrray and find combination in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, arraylist, arrayobject

I have 3 arrays as below

```
A: [
{
  "label": "100Watts",
  "value": "100Watts",
},
{
  "label": "135Watts",
  "value": "135Watts",
}  ]


B: [
{
"label": "Large|100cm",
"value": "Large|100cm"
},
{
"label": "Small|125mm",
"value": "Small|125mm"
}
]


C: [
{
  "label": "Black",
  "value": "Black",
},
{
  "label": "Black",
  "value": "Black",
}
]
```

I have one master array as below

```
 result:[
  { 
    "x_powerConsumption": "100Watts",
    "x_size": "Small|125mm",
    "x_color": "Black",
  },
  {
    "x_powerConsumption": "135Watts",
    "x_size": "Large|100cm",
    "x_color": "Black",
  }
  ]
```

My code as below

```
let newArray = A.filter(o1 => result.some(o2 => o1.label === o2.x_size));
let newArray2 = B.filter(o1 => result.some(o2 => o1.label === o2.x_powerConsumption));
                this.setState({selectedVarientOne: newArray[0].label, selectedVarientTwo:newArray2[0].label})
```

But my requirement is i need combination as below like

**Output : Black --> 100Watts --> Small|125mm**

But as per my above code it is coming like
Black --> 100Watts --> Large|100mm

Can anyone tell me how i can solve this?

Comment: Your question needs more clarification

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOB : If i choose Black then 100 Watts will be selected but Black + 100 Watts I need Small|125mm as size varient but as per my code I am getting size value Large|100cm which is wrong

Comment: Could you describe the necessary properties and remove the unnecessary properties? How is the data related?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I edit result array , Remove unused data from JSON

Comment: Why do you have 2 filters but 3 arrays? A filter returns an array. `newArray` and `A` contain the same elements and `newArray2` and `B` contain the same elements. How do you choose `100Watts`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik I tried like this newArray[0].label, newArray2[0].label

Comment: In that case try `A[0]`, `B[1]` and `C[0]`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Can you post answer so i can get better idea ? Because I really dont know how to compare 3 array so if you add answer or post it will be helpful forr me

Comment: I also don't know the logic. You didn't describe it. It looks like you're choosing the first elements or random elements.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I choose Color element As I mention in question , I have 3 dropdown and from that i select color black

Comment: It's impossible for me to answer because I don't understand why `Black --> 100Watts --> Small|125mm` is the expected result

Comment: @ThomasSablik It is my requirement because It is varient combination of my product

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand the logic of your requirement and the relation between `A`, `B`, `C` and `result`. You could either read the values from `A[0]`, `B[1]` and `C[0]` or from `result[0]`. I don't understand why you need the 3 arrays and the indexes `0`, `1`, `0` seem arbitrary for me.

Comment: @HarshalKalavadiya 2 answers have been added.. if any are correct can you please mark ;-;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm assuming that you want to match the array of objects to the main object

I just use a nest of for loops to see if `values` from an array(A,B, or C) match up with `values` from the main object(result) *from only the important keys in the result object of course*

```js
var A=[{"label":"100Watts","value":"100Watts"},{"label":"135Watts","value":"135Watts"}]
var B=[{"label":"Large|100cm","value":"Large|100cm"},{"label":"Small|125mm","value":"Small|125mm"}]


//now for function to correlate data(sry for late answer was afk lol)
function attribute(arr,result){
  const necessary_keys=["x_powerConsumption","x_size","x_color"]
  var toReturn=[] //array with output to return
  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    var arrValues=Object.values(arr[i]) //eg: A[0] would be ["100Watts","100Watts"]
    
    for(let j=0;j<result.length;j++){
      var resultValues=Object.keys(result[j])
      .filter(key=>necessary_keys.includes(key))
      .map(key=>result[j][key]) //result[0] would be ["100Watts","Small|125mm","Black"]
      
      if(resultValues.some(value=>arrValues.includes(value))){
        toReturn[i]=resultValues //["100Watts","Small|125mm","Black"] for arr[0]
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  return toReturn //all indexes with undefined dont correlate with result in any of its values
}


//now to use the function
let newArray=attribute(A,result)
let newArray2=attribute(B,result)

console.log("values from A:",newArray)
console.log("values from B:",newArray2)
```

```html
<script>
var result=[
  {
 "dynamicPropertyMapLong": {
  "sku-Equipment_x_color": 1,
  "sku-Equipment_x_size": 1,
  "sku-Equipment_x_powerConsumption": 3
 },
"x_UAE_installationPrice": 0,
"bundleLinks": [],
"largeImage": null,
"smallImage": null,
"listVolumePrice": null,
"onlineOnly": false,
"listPrices": {
  "aed": 100,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"configurationMetadata": [],
"largeImageURLs": [],
"x_skuCreationDate": null,
"productLine": null,
"listVolumePrices": {
  "aed": null,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"derivedSalePriceFrom": "aed",
"model": null,
"x_powerConsumption": "100Watts",
"barcode": null,
"salePriceEndDate": null,
"images": [],
"unitOfMeasure": null,
"primaryMediumImageURL": null,
"dynamicPropertyMapBigString": {},
"active": true,
"x_promotionDetails": "5 Percent Off: 5OFF5",
"thumbImageURLs": [],
"mediumImageURLs": [],
"primarySourceImageURL": null,
"x_description": null,
"sourceImageURLs": [],
"primarySmallImageURL": null,
"x_autoShipPrice": 0,
"productFamily": null,
"primaryThumbImageURL": null,
"nonreturnable": false,
"x_loyaltyLevel": "LEVEL2",
"displayName": "Three variant sku1",
"salePrices": {
  "aed": null,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"primaryFullImageURL": null,
"productListingSku": null,
"primaryLargeImageURL": null,
"derivedOnlineOnly": false,
"smallImageURLs": [],
"thumbnailImage": null,
"saleVolumePrices": {
  "aed": null,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"x_size": "Small|125mm",
"saleVolumePrice": null,
"salePriceStartDate": null,
"quantity": null,
"salePrice": null,
"fullImageURLs": [],
"x_isonSale": "Y",
"variantValuesOrder": {},
"x_color": "Black",
"soldAsPackage": true,
"listingSKUId": null,
"x_SAR_installationPrice": 0,
"repositoryId": "300003-1",
"derivedListPriceFrom": "aed",
"x_installationPrice": 0,
"x_costPrice": null,
"configurable": false,
"listPrice": 100
 },
{
"dynamicPropertyMapLong": {
  "sku-Equipment_x_color": 1,
  "sku-Equipment_x_size": 2,
  "sku-Equipment_x_powerConsumption": 1
},
"x_UAE_installationPrice": 0,
"bundleLinks": [],
"largeImage": null,
"smallImage": null,
"listVolumePrice": null,
"onlineOnly": false,
"listPrices": {
  "aed": 135,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"configurationMetadata": [],
"largeImageURLs": [],
"x_skuCreationDate": null,
"productLine": null,
"listVolumePrices": {
  "aed": null,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"derivedSalePriceFrom": "aed",
"model": null,
"x_powerConsumption": "135Watts",
"barcode": null,
"salePriceEndDate": null,
"images": [],
"unitOfMeasure": null,
"primaryMediumImageURL": null,
"dynamicPropertyMapBigString": {},
"active": true,
"x_promotionDetails": "5 Percent Off: 5OFF5",
"thumbImageURLs": [],
"mediumImageURLs": [],
"primarySourceImageURL": null,
"x_description": null,
"sourceImageURLs": [],
"primarySmallImageURL": null,
"x_autoShipPrice": 0,
"productFamily": null,
"primaryThumbImageURL": null,
"nonreturnable": false,
"x_loyaltyLevel": "LEVEL2",
"displayName": "sku3",
"salePrices": {
  "aed": null,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"primaryFullImageURL": null,
"productListingSku": null,
"primaryLargeImageURL": null,
"derivedOnlineOnly": false,
"smallImageURLs": [],
"thumbnailImage": null,
"saleVolumePrices": {
  "aed": null,
  "loyaltyProgram": null
},
"x_size": "Large|100cm",
"saleVolumePrice": null,
"salePriceStartDate": null,
"quantity": null,
"salePrice": null,
"fullImageURLs": [],
"x_isonSale": "Y",
"variantValuesOrder": {},
"x_color": "Black",
"soldAsPackage": true,
"listingSKUId": null,
"x_SAR_installationPrice": 0,
"repositoryId": "300003-3",
"derivedListPriceFrom": "aed",
"x_installationPrice": 0,
"x_costPrice": null,
"configurable": false,
"listPrice": 135
}
]
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other answer is correct, here is a shorter version:

```
result.map(({x_powerConsumption, x_size, x_color}) => ([
  A.find(el => el.label === x_powerConsumption).value,
  B.find(el => el.label === x_size).value,
  C.find(el => el.label === x_color).value
]))
```

Example:

```js
const A = [{ "label": "100Watts", "value": "100Watts" }, { "label": "135Watts", "value": "135Watts" }];
const B = [{ "label": "Large|100cm", "value": "Large|100cm" }, { "label": "Small|125mm", "value": "Small|125mm" }];
const C = [{ "label": "Black", "value": "Black" }, { "label": "Black", "value": "Black" }];

const result = [
  { "x_powerConsumption": "100Watts", "x_size": "Small|125mm", "x_color": "Black" },
  { "x_powerConsumption": "135Watts", "x_size": "Large|100cm", "x_color": "Black" }
];

console.log(result.map(({x_powerConsumption, x_size, x_color}) => ([
  A.find(el => el.label === x_powerConsumption).value,
  B.find(el => el.label === x_size).value,
  C.find(el => el.label === x_color).value
])));
```